# Boastful demographics

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

> I don't want to brag or anything, but I have more...
>   ...Azerbaijanis than Azerbaijan. (3)
>   ...Macedonians than Macedonia. (2)
>   ...Congolese than the Republic of Congo. (7, 15)
>   ...Georgians than Georgia. (7, 8)
>   ...Sothos than Lesotho. (5, 6)
>   ...Mongols than Mongolia. (4, 5)
>   ...Swazis than Swaziland. (8, 11)
>   ...Dominicans than Dominica. (14, 16)
>   ...Tajiks than Tajikistan. (1)

The final answer is the name of a country.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don’t want to brag or anything, but I have more

...Azerbaijanis than Azerbaijan. (3)

> Ir**a**n [A]

...Macedonians than Macedonia. (2)

> G**r**eece [R]

...Congolese than the Republic of Congo. (7, 15)

> Democr**a**tic Repu**b**lic of the Congo [A] [B]

...Georgians than Georgia. (7, 8)

> United **St**ates [S] [T]

...Sothos than Lesotho. (5, 6)

> Sout**h A**frica [H] [A]

...Mongols than Mongolia. (4, 5)

> Chi**na** [N] [A]

...Swazis than Swaziland. (8, 11)

> South Af**r**ic**a** [R] [A]

...Dominicans than Dominica. (14, 16)

> Dominican Repu**b**l**i**c?l [B][I]

...Tajiks than Tajikistan. (1)

> **A**fghanistan [A]

This yields

> ...**Arabs than Arabia**

Which might be

> **Egypt**, since it’s Arab population is greater than that of both Saudi Arabia and the Arabian Peninsula (thanks to @M Oehm!)

Comment: All correct. Nice work!

Comment: Thanks @jafe! Another fantastic puzzle from you, as per usual! :D

Answer (score 0):

funny partial answer:

> taking the n-th letter of each line, where n is the number(s) specified at the end of each line, will result in `eaehanosgohsnot`, reversed it's `tonshogsonaheae`. Adding spaces: `ton shogs on a heae`.
> if the last letter was a `p` it would actually be an almost perfect english sentence. But sadly it is not `p` so this whole approach seems wrong

Comment: This theory has more Holes than Holland ... `:)`

Comment: @MOehm I know.. I wouldn't have posted it if it weren't so funny